# What is a good example of a function returning another function?

Tags: swift

I saw in `Swift` that a function can return another function. I am not used with this concept and I am having difficulties understanding when would you wanna do this ?

Can someone point me to a good example for when you wanna return a function from another function ?

Comment: Maybe polymorphism or callbacks

Comment: An example will be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an actual example, a utility function I've been using in my own apps.

#### The problem:

As you probably know, drawing an image in code is accomplished by a patterned dance with this form:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(100,100), false, 0)
// do stuff
let im = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
// use im here...
```

There are several drawbacks to this structure: It's boring boilerplate, sure, but even worse, its key purpose is to generate the image, which happens on the next-to-last line — but then the image can't be used until *after the last line* (in other words, the structure "buries the lede", concealing its own purpose).

Also, it's error-prone (ever omit the `UIGraphicsEndImageContext` by mistake?). Plus any local variables interfere with local variables in the surrounding scope.

#### First solution:

All of these problems can be solved easily in Swift with a utility function that takes a closure:

```
func imageOfSize(size:CGSize, closure:() -> ()) -> UIImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0)
    closure()
    let result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return result
}
```

And you call it like this:

```
self.image = imageOfSize(CGSizeMake(100,100)) {
    let con = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    CGContextAddEllipseInRect(con, CGRectMake(0,0,100,100))
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(con, UIColor.blueColor().CGColor)
    CGContextFillPath(con)
}
```

That calling syntax is far more expressive of what we're really doing (we're making an image and using it!), and it omits the boilerplate and provides a contained scope for any local variable (though there were none in this example).

#### Good, but...

This is very good, but observe that I've had to supply two default values in the call to `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions`, namely `false` and `0`. Granted, these are the most common defaults. But it would be nice to write a version that lets us specify them, or at least the second parameter (opaque or not).

At the same time, it would be nice *not to have to specify this all the time*, since `false` is in fact the most common value. Thus what we want is an *optional* second parameter, `opaque:Bool = false`.

The trouble is that you *can't have an optional second parameter when the third parameter is a closure*; the compiler complains when you try to make the call while omitting the second parameter.

#### Second solution: a function that makes a function!

The solution is to "curry" the function into two functions, where:

- One function takes a single optional `opaque` parameter.
- The other function takes a closure.

Like this:

```
func drawnImage (opaque:Bool = false) -> (CGSize, () -> ()) -> UIImage {
    func imageOfSize(size:CGSize, closure:() -> ()) -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, opaque, 0)
        closure()
        let result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return result
    }
    return imageOfSize
}
```

Now you can call it like this:

```
self.image = drawnImage()(CGSizeMake(100,100)) {
    let con = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    CGContextAddEllipseInRect(con, CGRectMake(0,0,100,100))
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(con, UIColor.blueColor().CGColor)
    CGContextFillPath(con)
}
```

Or, if opaque, like this:

```
self.image = drawnImage(opaque:true)(CGSizeMake(100,100)) {
    let con = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    CGContextAddEllipseInRect(con, CGRectMake(0,0,100,100))
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(con, UIColor.blueColor().CGColor)
    CGContextFillPath(con)
}
```

Thus the ability of a function to generate a function in Swift lets us bend the language to our will, giving us a convenient calling syntax in both cases.

Answer (score 4):

First of all I want to say that I am not really well-read in Swift, but this holds for any function returning functions:

Also I have to note that this is much easier to understand if you understand [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying).

Have a look at [partial function application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application). In partial application, you take a function (lets take a simple `add` function as an example) and supply it with fewer parameters than it actually needs to yield it's supposed result. The result if this is a function which takes the rest of the parameters. A curried `add` would look something like this:

```
func add(a: Int)(b: Int) -> Int {
    return a + b
}
```

You can now do this:

```
var add10 = add(10)
println(add10(b: 4)) // prints 14
```

For actually being able to partially apply functions and not explicitly having to curry every one of them, have a look at [this](https://gist.github.com/kristopherjohnson/4ee565cfcdf912deacf6) gist.

Answer (score 0):

```
func returnfunction() -> ((Int,Int) -> Double)
{
    var y = 0

    func functionToReturn(number1:Int, number2:Int) -> Double {

        y = number1 * number2
        return Double(y)
    }

   return functionToReturn   //return function
}

var result = returnfunction()
result (2,4)
```